# How do I spilt the footer into different widths?

Tags: css, wordpress, widget

Hi there i'm using Wordpress and the Wootique theme, the theme supports a variety of footer widget layouts just 1 or split into 2, 3 or 4 columns but I want to change it so if its set to 3 columns that it will be the first footer widget is half the overall size and the other 2 and then split between the remaining half.

Here is the current css how do I split that so its 48% 24% and 24%?

```css
/* 3 columns */

#footer-widgets.col-3 .block {
  width: 30.75%;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 3.8%;
}
#footer-widgets.col-3 .footer-widget-3 {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
#footer-widgets.col-3 .block {
  width: 24%;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 3.8%;
}
#footer-widgets.col-3 .block:first-child {
  width: 48%;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, please explain the each classes. Its hard to assume things.
I assume that `#footer-widgets.col-3 .block` is for the 3 divs that have equal widths. that would total somewhere near 100%

Comment: I don't think it worked but I'm going to have to come back to this later my domain has gone down again, so sick of this

Comment: It went down *again*? ... Is this random? Or is it while you're working?

Comment: Yeah i'm having problems with my new domain I had to register with some else to get a .ie address then point the name servers to my hosting but for some reason it keeps going down every few hours, the domain was new so maybe it just needs a few days but I changed all my wordpress site url to the new domain so when that one goes down I can't do anything.

Comment: Oh no wait it totally did my mistake! Awesome thanks